How to add superscript to title in ggcorrplot?
How can I make the title of a ggcorrplot have superscript? When I try using the expression() function I get an error Error in title != "" : comparison is not allowed for expressions.
library(ggcorrplot)
#> Warning: package 'ggcorrplot' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.2.3

# Compute a correlation matrix
data(mtcars)
corr <- round(cor(mtcars), 1)
corr
#>       mpg  cyl disp   hp drat   wt qsec   vs   am gear carb
#> mpg   1.0 -0.9 -0.8 -0.8  0.7 -0.9  0.4  0.7  0.6  0.5 -0.6
#> cyl  -0.9  1.0  0.9  0.8 -0.7  0.8 -0.6 -0.8 -0.5 -0.5  0.5
#> disp -0.8  0.9  1.0  0.8 -0.7  0.9 -0.4 -0.7 -0.6 -0.6  0.4
#> hp   -0.8  0.8  0.8  1.0 -0.4  0.7 -0.7 -0.7 -0.2 -0.1  0.7
#> drat  0.7 -0.7 -0.7 -0.4  1.0 -0.7  0.1  0.4  0.7  0.7 -0.1
#> wt   -0.9  0.8  0.9  0.7 -0.7  1.0 -0.2 -0.6 -0.7 -0.6  0.4
#> qsec  0.4 -0.6 -0.4 -0.7  0.1 -0.2  1.0  0.7 -0.2 -0.2 -0.7
#> vs    0.7 -0.8 -0.7 -0.7  0.4 -0.6  0.7  1.0  0.2  0.2 -0.6
#> am    0.6 -0.5 -0.6 -0.2  0.7 -0.7 -0.2  0.2  1.0  0.8  0.1
#> gear  0.5 -0.5 -0.6 -0.1  0.7 -0.6 -0.2  0.2  0.8  1.0  0.3
#> carb -0.6  0.5  0.4  0.7 -0.1  0.4 -0.7 -0.6  0.1  0.3  1.0

# Corrleation matrx without title
ggcorrplot(corr,
           hc.order = TRUE, type = "lower",
           lab = TRUE,
           ggtheme = ggplot2::theme_bw())



ggcorrplot(corr,
           hc.order = TRUE, type = "lower",
           lab = TRUE,
           title = expression(Temperature~(degree*C)),
           ggtheme = ggplot2::theme_bw())
#> Error in title != "": comparison is not allowed for expressions

sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
#> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
#> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22631)
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8 
#> [2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
#> [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
#> [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
#> [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#> [1] ggcorrplot_0.1.4.1 ggplot2_3.5.0     
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] Rcpp_1.0.11      plyr_1.8.8       compiler_4.2.1   pillar_1.9.0    
#>  [5] highr_0.9        tools_4.2.1      digest_0.6.29    evaluate_0.15   
#>  [9] lifecycle_1.0.3  tibble_3.2.1     gtable_0.3.1     pkgconfig_2.0.3 
#> [13] rlang_1.1.1      reprex_2.0.2     cli_3.6.1        rstudioapi_0.14 
#> [17] yaml_2.3.5       xfun_0.39        fastmap_1.1.0    withr_2.5.0     
#> [21] stringr_1.5.0    dplyr_1.1.3      knitr_1.39       generics_0.1.3  
#> [25] fs_1.6.3         vctrs_0.6.3      grid_4.2.1       tidyselect_1.2.0
#> [29] glue_1.6.2       R6_2.5.1         fansi_1.0.4      rmarkdown_2.14  
#> [33] farver_2.1.1     reshape2_1.4.4   magrittr_2.0.3   scales_1.3.0    
#> [37] htmltools_0.5.5  colorspace_2.0-3 labeling_0.4.2   utf8_1.2.3      
#> [41] stringi_1.7.12   munsell_0.5.0

Created on 2024-04-19 with reprex v2.0.2

Your code works fine for me (using ggcorrplot ‘0.1.4.1’):  https://i.sstatic.net/4ADfG.png

Interesting - I am also using version 0.1.4.1

One difference is that use ggplot2 3.5.0

I thought the same thing - I updated ggplot2 to 3.5.0, started a new R session, and still got the same error.

The code is working - I had to download the latest versions of R (I was using 4.2.1 - now using 4.3.3) and Rstudio to make it work.
